# Karma how to enter input field and submit form using jquery

Tags: automated-tests, karma-runner

I have following Karma config

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Thu Oct 24 2013 16:41:13 GMT+0200 (CEST)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    frameworks: ['ng-scenario'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'lib/jquery.js',
      'test/**/*.js'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [

    ],


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress', 'junit', 'growl', 'coverage'
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,

    // cli runner port
    runnerPort: 9100,

    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,

    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // Start these browsers, currently available:
    // - Chrome
    // - ChromeCanary
    // - Firefox
    // - Opera
    // - Safari (only Mac)
    // - PhantomJS
    // - IE (only Windows)
    browsers: ['PhantomJS', 'Chrome'],


    // If browser does not capture in given timeout [ms], kill it
    captureTimeout: 10000,

    proxies: {
        '/': 'http://localhost:8080/' // Keep this in sync with localhost port in Gruntfile.
    },

    urlRoot: '/_karma_/',

    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

And I have my test case:

```
'use strict'

describe("A suite", function() {
  it("contains spec with an expectation", function() {
    browser().navigateTo('/')

    $('#username').val('test@example.com')
    $('#password').val('*******')
    $('.submitLogin').click()       

    expect(browser().location().url()).toBe('/welcome')

  });
});
```

I can navigate browser using `browser().navigateTo('/url');`

But I can't force it to submit my values. Any ideas how could I achieve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to use jquery? What about using something like the following (the example assumes the login form has id `login`)?

```
using('#login').input('username').enter('test@example.com');
using('#login').input('password').enter('*******');
element('.submitLogin').click();
```

If jquery is essential you might look into putting your jquery into an [`element(...).query(fn)`](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.e2e-testing) block.

Comment: Ok I made is using `element('#login').val('test@example.org')` and as you described with submit login above.

Comment: Since I forgot about this question that I actually solved you deserve a solution points @lorcan

Comment: Great, but please don't mark it unless the answer is correct (I think it is).